# AddRange throws "Cannot implicitly convert type" exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have no idea why this is not working:

```
    Dictionary<string, List<GameObject>> prefabs = new Dictionary<string, List<GameObject>>();
    List<GameObject> slotPrefabs = new List<GameObject>();

    // yadda yadda yadda

    if (prefabs.ContainsKey(slot))
    {
        prefabs[slot] = prefabs[slot].AddRange(slotPrefabs);
    }
    else
    {
        prefabs.Add(slot, slotPrefabs);
    }
```

It's giving me:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I just want to add to the existing list of the dictionary key if it already exists.

Comment: I'd suggest using `TryGetValue` rather than `ContainsKey` then `[]` - for performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AddRange(slotPrefabs)` is a void method, meaning it does not return any value back. Therefore you cannot assign it to a variable.

so instead of `prefabs[slot] = prefabs[slot].AddRange(slotPrefabs);` , it should just be `prefabs[slot].AddRange(slotPrefabs);`